# Escape byte array error, if file not exist

Tags: c#

I need to send file like byte array.

First i create path to file:

```
saveLocation = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/temp"), filename);
```

where file name is name of file.
When i define path I must call other method:

```
public string upload_b(string filepath)
{
    SomeService service = new SomeService();
    byte[] b = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
    return service.upload_b(b);
}
```

Now if I not have filename I get error, because file cannot be find.

I was think to use `if` to check it and than define byte array , but i cannot define variable in `if` and i don't know size of byte array to define it before.

Please help,
Thank You

Comment: why not stop the upload if the file does not exists? if (!File.Exists(filepath)) return;

Comment: @fuchs777: The questioner already has the idea of checking for file existence before reading bytes from the file, and there exactly is the actual problem: Where to declare and where to assign a value to the byte array..?

Comment: just return before you even create the byte array or the service, right at the beginning of the function... just don't do anything if the file does not exists... there seems to be no reason to upload an empty byte array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare the variable before the if-statement and assign a value to it inside a if-statement. You don't need to know the capacity of the array this way. Or you could catch the FileNotFound-Exception at the location where you are trying to access the file, this would be a better solution, but only if usually the file is existing and ONLY SOMETIMES the file is not existing.

Edit, i am thinking of something like following:

```
byte[] b;
if (File.Exists(filepath))
{
   b = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
   //...
}
else
{
   //...
}
```

Or alternatively the try-catch approach:

```
byte[] b;
try
{
   b = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
   //...
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e)
{
   //...
}
```

Comment: When I try I was think to work, but i getting error that b is unassigned.. :/ Thanks for answer.

Comment: This is because you proceed with the upload after the if-else-block (or after the try-catch block), do the upload inside the if-statement (or inside the try-block), there b is always assigned.

Comment: Thanx it is work now, when i put code for return in if ,else block it is help.